# Multiply same numpy array with scalars multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, tensor, array-broadcasting

I have a 3D NumPy array of size `(9,9,200)` and a 2D array of size `(200,200)`.
I want to take each channel of shape `(9,9,1)` and generate an array `(9,9,200)`, every channel multiplied 200 times by 1 scalar in a single row, and average it such that the resultant array is `(9,9,1)`.
Basically, if there are `n` channels in an input array, I want each channel multiplied `n` times and averaged - and this should happen for all channels. Is there an efficient way to do so?

So far what I have is this -

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(9,9,200)
nchannel = arr.shape[-1]
transform = np.array([np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(nchannel,)) for i in range(nchannel)])
  for channel in range(nchannel):
    # The below line needs optimization
    temp = [arr[:,:,i] * transform[channel][i] for i in range(nchannel)]
    arr[:,:,channel] = np.sum(temp, axis=0)/nchannel
```

Edit :
A sample image demonstrating what I am looking for. Here `nchannel` = 3.
[image]
The input image is `arr`. The final image is the transformed `arr`.

Comment: can you post a minimal executable example? I am not sure what arr and nchannel is...

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want, What is the 2D array for? Where do the n scalars come from?

Comment: Maybe to add to sehan2's comment, it would be very helpful if it would be a toy example which is not `9 x 9 x 200`, but something like `2 x 2 x 3`  with an expected output :-) I unfortunately do not understand your problem from the question..

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @sehan2. @user16648691 the 2D array is a `nxn` matrix, each row corresponding to n scalars that one channel will be multiplied with.

Comment: @André you can replace the value 200 with 3, my question would still be valid. I also posted a pseudo-code with your suggested dimensions to clarify things a little bit.

Comment: If I understood this right it's a tensor multiplication by a matrix then averaging on axis -1?

Comment: @user16648691 I suppose yes, you can call that. You do the multiplication and averaging for every channel.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np

n_channels = 3
scalar_size = 2

t = np.ones((n_channels,scalar_size,scalar_size)) # scalar array
m = np.random.random((n_channels,n_channels)) # letters array

print(m)
print(t)
m_av = np.mean(m, axis=1)
print(m_av)

for i in range(n_channels):
    t[i] = t[i]*m_av1[i]

print(t)
```

output:

```
[[0.04601533 0.05851365 0.03893352]
 [0.7954655  0.08505869 0.83033369]
 [0.59557455 0.09632997 0.63723506]]

[[[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]]

[0.04782083 0.57028596 0.44304653]

[[[0.04782083 0.04782083]
  [0.04782083 0.04782083]]

 [[0.57028596 0.57028596]
  [0.57028596 0.57028596]]

 [[0.44304653 0.44304653]
  [0.44304653 0.44304653]]]
```

Comment: Hi @user16648691, I do not think this is the correct solution. I added a diagram to better emphasize what I am looking for.

Comment: so here we have a 2x2x3 scalar array and a 3x3 array that contains the channels right? First for every channel of size 3 we get a 2x2x3 array that is basically the multiplication element wise of the scalar array by every element of the channel ? So you end up with a 2x2x3x3 array that you finally average on the last axxis to get a 2x2x3 array ? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If that's the case I would first average every channel so you get a 1D array os size n_channel that you can multiply elementwise with your scalar array. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a simple matrix multiplication along the last axis:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(9,9,200)
transform = np.random.uniform(size=(200, 200)) / 200

arr = arr @ transform
```